# Python Dataframe wrong slicing

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Hi my code looks like this:

```
data = pd.read_csv('people_wiki.csv')
obama = data.loc[data['name'].str.strip() == 'Barack Obama']
print(str(obama['text']))
```

my output is:

```
35817    barack hussein obama ii brk husen bm born augu...
Name: text, dtype: object
```

I don't know why do i see this 35817 - which is index in my data and both "Name", "dtype" values? i have tried different approach but nothing worked so far

Comment: You get `one element Series` by filtering by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing), it is expected output.

Comment: But for example if i use `obama = data.loc[35817]` and then `print(obama['text']` i get whole text as an output, not just "barack hussein obama ii brk husen bm born augu..."

Comment: It is different, you select by index and columns values - then get scalar.

Comment: It is same like `obama = data.loc[35817, 'text']`

Comment: So what should i do to do it properly?

Comment: Hard question,  it depends what need... select or filter? And if filter output is always one item (one element Series) ?

Comment: From my data i need to select every row which contains "Barack Obama" in 'text' column into new data frame. I can achive that with what i wrote in my post but 'text' column contains only very small part of text which is my problem

Comment: Boolean indexing always returns a slice (of a Series or a DataFrame, based on where you use it). If the result is a single row it doesn't suddenly start returning scalars because it would break everybody's code. If you are sure that you'll get a single item, just call `item()` at the end (`obama['text'].item()`) will be a scalar value and it will not show you the name or the dtype of the Series)

Comment: This worked just fine. In this case i just have a single item. Would this work if my `obama = data.loc[data['name'].str.strip() == 'Barack Obama']` returned 2 rows?

Comment: @ayhan - very nice comment, maybe if give some example it should be nice answer... ;)

Comment: @Drac0 - if it return `2 rows` function `item()` failed. And it is reason why boolean indexing return `Series with 1,2, N elements`..

Comment: @jezrael I probably saw it in one of your answers but I am still looking for a duplicate. :)

Comment: So i added duplicate row at the end of my data now after i `obama = data.loc[data['name'].str.strip() == 'Barack Obama']` i receive DataFrame(2,3) and .item() doesnt work. I dont know if its something in my data but in previous case i have done i didnt had problem with such a slicing at all

Comment: So are you trying to get the full contents from the cell (and cells in the case of duplicates)?

Comment: Yes, full content.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You'll want to use `.values` to get the cell content:

```
data = pd.read_csv('people_wiki.csv')
obama = data.loc[data['name'].str.strip() == 'Barack Obama']

# This will give you a list of the cell contents for all of the matches:
# one match: ['example cell content']
# two matches: ['example cell content 1', 'example cell content 2']
print(obama['text'].values)

# You'll just need to specify which you want to use as a string
print(obama['text'].values[0]
```

Comment: Looks fine, Thanks and Thanks everyone for trying to make me understand this :)